# How to get the text background color (RGB values) of a pdf file?

Tags: java, pdf, background-color

does anyone know how I can find out the text background color (RGB) of a pdf file? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no background.
PDF is a print media oriented, and background is always white. An object (drawing, image etc.) is beyond the text and makes "background". You have to detect this object and get color of it (this can be not easy too, due to different color spaces).

Comment: ok Thank You!...thn is it possible to get a text bakground image (RGB)  from a PDF file...

Answer (score 1):

If the PDF contains layers you might be able to think about a background layer but otherwise there is no real concept of a background image - it is what you choose to interpet.

A PDF is a vector image which is drawn and you see the finished article.